# Oracle printing (multi-value) VARRAY type using stored procedure

Tags: oracle

I'm stuck on getting my stored procedure to work because I made a VARRAY data type to store all information about allergies, my goal is to input an integer primary key and the result will return the information respected to that primary key.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE showAllergies
    (
        P_PID IN NUMBER,
        P_f_name OUT VARCHAR2,
        P_l_name OUT VARCHAR2,
        P_allergies OUT allergy_ty
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT p.name.f_name, 
               p.name.l_name, 
               al.allergies
        INTO P_f_name, 
             P_l_name, 
             P_allergies
        FROM PATIENT_obj_table p
        INNER JOIN PATIENT_allergies al ON p.PID = al.PID
        WHERE 
            al.PID = P_PID;
    END showAllergies;

--Must do this in order to execute multiple output parameters
set serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
fname       VARCHAR2(25);
lname       VARCHAR2(25);
allergies   allergy_ty;
total       NUMBER(2,0);
begin
    --select value(a) INTO allergies FROM PATIENT_allergies WHERE a.PID = 100; 
    total := allergies.limit;
    showAllergies(101, fname, lname, allergies);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('firstName: '||fname||', lastName: '||lname||' Allergies ');
    FOR i in 1 .. total
    LOOP DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(allergies(i));
    end loop;
  end;
END;


CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE allergy_ty AS VARRAY(10)
OF VARCHAR2(30);
```

I don't know how get VARRAY type to print using stored procedure do ya'll lend me some help? -Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post how tables you use look like, so I'm going to guess. Moreover, I'll use Scott's `EMP` and `DEPT` tables to *simulate* what you have; I'll display department (which is your "patient") and employees who work in that department (which is "allergies" patients suffer from).

```
SQL> -- this table simulates your PATIENT table
SQL> select * From dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL> -- this table simulates your ALLERGIES table
SQL> select deptno, ename from emp;

    DEPTNO ENAME
---------- ----------
        20 SMITH
        30 ALLEN
        30 WARD
        20 JONES
        30 MARTIN
        30 BLAKE
        10 CLARK
        20 SCOTT
        10 KING
        30 TURNER
        20 ADAMS
        30 JAMES
        20 FORD
        10 MILLER

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

This is more or less code you wrote; note the way I selected values into `p_allergies` parameter - not with a join, but a separate query:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE allergy_ty AS VARRAY(10) OF VARCHAR2(30);
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace procedure showallergies
  2    (p_pid in number,
  3     p_f_name out varchar2,
  4     p_l_name out varchar2,
  5     p_allergies out allergy_ty
  6    )
  7  is
  8  begin
  9    select d.dname, d.loc
 10      into p_f_name, p_l_name
 11      from dept d
 12      where d.deptno = p_pid;
 13
 14    select e.ename
 15      bulk collect into p_allergies
 16      from emp e
 17      where e.deptno = p_pid;
 18  end;
 19  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

Let's see how it works:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
  2    fname varchar2(20);
  3    lname varchar2(20);
  4    allergies allergy_ty;
  5  begin
  6    showallergies(10, fname, lname, allergies);
  7    dbms_output.put_line(fname ||', '|| lname);
  8
  9    for i in 1 .. allergies.count loop
 10      dbms_output.put_line(allergies(i));
 11    end loop;
 12  end;
 13  /
ACCOUNTING, NEW YORK
CLARK
KING
MILLER

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Works OK. Now, try to do the same with your tables.